# Guidance Needed: Connecting an On-Premises SQL Database to a SharePoint Online Column via Azure Web App Hosting WCF Service

Tags: sharepoint-online, sql, wcf, azure-service-bus, hybrid

I'm working on a project that involves connecting an on-premises SQL Database table to a SharePoint Online lookup column. As a part of the process, I've successfully set up an Azure Web App to host a WCF Service, which is connected to the database server through a hybrid connection.

While I've been able to progress to this point, I'm finding it challenging to discern the next steps in integrating this setup with SharePoint Online. A significant portion of the resources and walkthroughs I've found appear to be outdated or not directly applicable to my situation.

Could you provide guidance on how to proceed? Specifically, I'm looking for the steps to integrate the WCF service (hosted on Azure and connected to the on-premises SQL database) with SharePoint Online. I am aware of using Business Connectivity Services and SharePoint Designer, but understand these are less favored in modern SharePoint Online development. Is there a more current, recommended approach?

Any advice or resources that could point me in the right direction would be immensely appreciated.

Best regards,